# Is there a built-in way to loop through the properties of an object?

Tags: javascript, iteration, handlebars.js, mustache

Is there a Mustache / Handlebars way of looping through an **object** properties?

So with

```
var o = {
  bob : 'For sure',
  roger: 'Unknown',
  donkey: 'What an ass'
}
```

Can I then do something *in the template engine* that would be equivalent to

```
for(var prop in o)
{
    // with say, prop a variable in the template and value the property value
}
```

?

Answer (score 495, accepted):

### Built-in support since Handlebars 1.0rc1

Support for this functionality [has been added](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/9589ab89492c23e1d201f61617ae2a3bf54a0afc/lib/handlebars/base.js#L80-L86) to Handlebars.js, so there is no more need for external helpers.

### How to use it

For arrays:

```
{{#each myArray}}
    Index: {{@index}} Value = {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

For objects:

```
{{#each myObject}}
    Key: {{@key}} Value = {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

Note that only properties passing the [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) test will be enumerated.

Comment: This doesn't work with nested objects. I tried {{#each myObject}}
    <li> {{data.title}} </li> and it returns <li></li>

Comment: @Rafi: one cannot make much sense of that without knowing your data structure though.

Comment: I had a list of strings i used as input for my template, it worked greate with the following template code {{#.}}
        <li>{{this}}</li>
        {{/.}}

Comment: @Ben: can you make this the accepted answer?  The older answers imply that this is not actually built-in, which was true at the time, but are now very misleading.

Comment: @Rafi: don't you mean {{this.title}}?

Comment: Ok this slightly doesnt make sense. As I understand {{#each <key>}} has to be an explicit key, where did you get myArray and myObject from? Your code would not work on a top-level object that doesnt have pre-defined keys. How do you this generically, over an object?

Comment: @qodeninja: Simple: the same way you refer to the values in the examples above -- with `{{#each this}}`. Your choice of terms is also confusing (what makes one object "top level" and another not? what are "pre-defined" keys exactly? etc), so you might want to revisit these concepts.

Comment: @Jon thanks for explaining this, I'm just getting into handlebars. Top-level as in not a subobject. data = { key1: val1, key2 : val2, sub1 : { } }, pre-defined keys, as in you have to explicitly specify the keys in the template. If you dont know what the keys are how do you do this? But you explained by using `this` so I'll try that! But  the mystery is where you go myArray and myObject from, you should update your code to reflect an example that will work to help newbies who dont understand what you're implying

Comment: Not working for me. `Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed {0: Name can't be blank, 1: Zip code can't be blank, 2: Company type can't be blank, 3: Address line can't be blank, 4: Country can't be blank, 5: State can't be blank}`

Comment: @Serg: Handlebars? What version?

Comment: Latest of this comment. 1.3.0.

Comment: if not mistaken then only with v1.1.0 this is available, but great answer thanks.

Comment: How do you do this for only a specific whitelist of properties?

Comment: @MarcoPrins: In Handlebars at least, AFAIK you write your own helper. Handlebars is notorious for choosing to provide such a minimal amount of logic built-in that you cannot even stitch a whitelist together.

Comment: Using node and `mustache --version` is 2.3... **ERROR**: Error: Unclosed section "each paths". Where *paths* is the *myObject* name.

Comment: What if you need to do some manipulation or calculation to `@key`? For example the equivalent of `@key - 1`. How is that possible? In a lot of templates you need to do things such as checking the previous value within an array to avoid displaying duplicate headings, etc.

Answer (score 74):

It's actually quite easy to implement as a helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('eachProperty', function(context, options) {
    var ret = "";
    for(var prop in context)
    {
        ret = ret + options.fn({property:prop,value:context[prop]});
    }
    return ret;
});
```

Then using it like so:

```
{{#eachProperty object}}
    {{property}}: {{value}}<br/>
{{/eachProperty }}
```

Comment: Looks good, do you need to add a hasOwnProperty check inside the loop so you're not iterating over prototype properties?

Comment: Great solution @Ben. In case anyone is trying to use this with Ember, see my answer below for the solution to get it working.

Answer (score 29):

**EDIT: Handlebars now has a built-in way of accomplishing this; see the [selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17516837/117331) above.
When working with plain Mustache, the below still applies.**

Mustache can iterate over items in an array. So I'd suggest creating a separate data object formatted in a way Mustache can work with:

```
var o = {
  bob : 'For sure',
  roger: 'Unknown',
  donkey: 'What an ass'
},
mustacheFormattedData = { 'people' : [] };

for (var prop in o){
  if (o.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
    mustacheFormattedData['people'].push({
      'key' : prop,
      'value' : o[prop]
     });
  }
}
```

Now, your Mustache template would be something like:

```
{{#people}}
  {{key}} : {{value}}
{{/people}}
```

Check out the "Non-Empty Lists" section here: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

Comment: Ended up going with your suggestion as I need to pass some additional sub properties anyway. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks very much, your idea saved me another day of looking of alternatives.  This line is the key mustacheFormattedData = { 'people' : [] };

Comment: How would you do this with an array of "o" objects?

Answer (score 5):

This is @Ben's answer updated for use with Ember...note you have to use `Ember.get` because context is passed in as a String.

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('eachProperty', function(context, options) {
  var ret = "";
  var newContext = Ember.get(this, context);
  for(var prop in newContext)
  {
    if (newContext.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      ret = ret + options.fn({property:prop,value:newContext[prop]});
    }
  }
  return ret;
});
```

Template:

```
{{#eachProperty object}}
  {{key}}: {{value}}<br/>
{{/eachProperty }}
```

Comment: Thanks @flynfish. context is a string in Ember?? that seems.. somewhat odd.

Comment: Yea I'm not really sure since I am new to Ember and still trying to find my way around it.

Answer (score 1):

@Amit's answer is good because it will work in both Mustache and Handlebars.

As far as Handlebars-only solutions, I've seen a few and I like the `each_with_key` block helper at https://gist.github.com/1371586 the best.

- It allows you to iterate over object literals without having to restructure them first, and
- It gives you control over what you call the key variable.  With many other solutions you have to be careful about using object keys named `'key'`, or `'property'`, etc.

Comment: Nice find.  Just a warning to other readers:  the "key_value" helper in this gist has a bug in it.  Read the comments for how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Ben's solution, my use case to display only particular fields in order

with object

Code:

```
    handlebars.registerHelper('eachToDisplayProperty', function(context, toDisplays, options) {
    var ret = "";
    var toDisplayKeyList = toDisplays.split(",");
    for(var i = 0; i < toDisplayKeyList.length; i++) {
        toDisplayKey = toDisplayKeyList[i];
        if(context[toDisplayKey]) {
            ret = ret + options.fn({
                property : toDisplayKey,
                value : context[toDisplayKey]
            });
        }

    }
    return ret;
});
```

Source object:

```
   { locationDesc:"abc", name:"ghi", description:"def", four:"you wont see this"}
```

Template:

```
{{#eachToDisplayProperty this "locationDesc,description,name"}}
    <div>
        {{property}} --- {{value}}
    </div>
    {{/eachToDisplayProperty}}
```

---

Output:

```
locationDesc --- abc
description --- def
name --- ghi
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a helper function for mustacheJS, without pre-formatting the data and instead getting it during render.

```
var data = {
    valueFromMap: function() {
        return function(text, render) {
            // "this" will be an object with map key property
            // text will be color that we have between the mustache-tags
            // in the template
            // render is the function that mustache gives us

            // still need to loop since we have no idea what the key is
            // but there will only be one
            for ( var key in this) {
                if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    return render(this[key][text]);
                }
            }
        };
    },

    list: {
        blueHorse: {
            color: 'blue'
        },

        redHorse: {
            color: 'red'
        }
    }
};
```

Template:

```
{{#list}}
    {{#.}}<span>color: {{#valueFromMap}}color{{/valueFromMap}}</span> <br/>{{/.}}
{{/list}}
```

Outputs:

```
color: blue
color: red
```

(order might be random - it's a map)
This might be useful if you know the map element that you want. Just watch out for falsy values.

Answer (score -2):

I was using old version `1.0.beta.6` of handlebars, i think somewhere during 1.1 - 1.3 this functionality was added, so updating to 1.3.0 solved the issue, here is the usage:

Usage:

```
{{#each object}}
  Key {{@key}} : Value {{this}}
{{/people}}
```