# Accessing values of a map inside handlebar template file

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

In the handlebar template file 
where content is elements of the map:

```
map {<"1" -> [{:a => "1",:b => "as"},{:a => "2", :b => "hj"}]>,<"4" -> [{:a => "we",:b => "kj"}]>,......}
```

I want to know how to iterate over the elements of all structures of each list for each key of the map inside handlebar file

**EDIT**

```
{{# each content}}
  key: {{@key}} value = {{this}}
  ....
{{/each}}
```

value is list of structures.
I want to iterate over the items in each structure in the list how to do that

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838925/is-there-any-method-to-iterate-a-map-with-handlebars-js

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I have edited.Please have a look.

Comment: I can't begin to understand what your `map` data structure is.

Comment: @76484  key: string, value: list of structures. structure having 2 strings

Comment: Hmm. What are the two strings in "structure"?

Comment: Additionally, it would be helpful if you added your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely check the handlebars documentation first.

You can pass a whole Map into your HTML and then iterate and use your helper (aCustomHelper). The '@key' keyword refers to the key of the map and the 'this' keyword refers to the value of the map (example-map-object).

```
{{#each example-map-object}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{{this}}}</td>
        <td>{{{@key}}}</td>
        <td>{{{aCustomHelper @key this}}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

In the example below, you can see how you can access a Set object by key and value:

```
<select>
    {{#each example-set-object}}
          <option value="{{@value}}">{{@key}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

In the example below, you can see how you can access a Map by it's key values, which is very handy indeed:

```
{{#each example-map-object}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{{this.id}}}</td>
        <td>{{{this.customerName}}}</td>
        <td>{{{this.date}}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

So the answer to your question is that YES, you can most certainly do what you want and pass the whole map as a parameter to your helper method.

```
{{yourHelper example-map-object}}
```