# Key-values arrays

Tags: php, mustache

I want to iterate through an array like this one:

```
array(
   ['aaa'] => ['a'],
   ['bbb'] => ['b']
)
```

Usually, I would do it this way:

```
{{#array}}{{array}}{{/array}} // 'a' 'b'
```

But - how can I display the current key in the loop above? I want to display something like `'aaa' 'a' 'bbb' 'b'`. Is it possible?

Comment: Can't you use a foreach? Foreach($value as $key => $row) { }

Comment: @Pilatus, he is using mustache

Comment: Theres no built in way to do this..

Comment: So the only way is putting php code to the .mustache file?

Comment: I've read about handlebars...does that have any functions to do this?

Comment: Handlebars is javascript and not php

Comment: have a look at solution in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058774/handlebars-mustache-is-there-a-built-in-way-to-loop-through-the-properties-of

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to iterate over an associative array in Mustache. It sees your associative array as a "context" rather than an iterable list.

You can make it iterable by preparing a View, or by pre-processing your data to make it into a more Mustache-friendly format. You could do this with a foreach loop before you pass the data into Mustache, but the easiest way to do this is probably by wrapping it in a Presenter. Try this one on for size:

https://gist.github.com/bobthecow/61161639d8be82a75b5e

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$a=array('aaa' => 'a', 'bbb' => 'b');
print_r($a);
foreach($a as $key => $val){
    echo $key . ' - ' . $val . '<br>';
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [aaa] => a
    [bbb] => b
)
aaa - a
bbb - b
```