# iterate through Child elements in Handlebars

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

As an example I have the following dataset

```
  dataset = {header: ' header' } 

  dateline = { content: 'list of dates' } 

  monday = [
        { food:'teacake' , drink:'orange' } 
        ]

  tuesday = [
        { food:'eggs' , drink:'beer' } 
        ]    

  dateline.monday = monday
  dateline.tuesday = tuesday
  dataset.dateline = dateline
```

What I want to do is use handle bars to run though the days , I thought this could be done using child.

```
  <script id="mwl707" type="text/x-handlebars-template">        
  {{#each dateline.children }}
    <span>{{food}} : {{drink}}</span>
  {{/each}}
  </script>
```

but I cant get it to work , any help please ?   [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwl707/AgCBb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your fiddle so it works: http://jsfiddle.net/AgCBb/1/

You should not wrap your objects monday and tuesday again in `[]` parenthesis, it is an unnecessary extra level to parse. Just make an days Array in your parent object, as arrays are much easier to parse in Handlebars.

```
dataset = {header: ' header' } //
dateline = { content: 'list of dates' } 
monday  =  { "food":"teacake" , "drink":"orange" }
tuesday = { "food":"eggs" , "drink":"beer" }

dateline.days = []
dateline.days.push(monday)
dateline.days.push(tuesday)
```

Then you can parse it like this:

```
{{#dateline.days }}
  <span>{{food}} : {{drink}}</span>
{{/dateline.days}}
```

Also make sure you pass valid JSON to your templates. If unsure you might check your JSON with http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

Handlebars does not provide a built-in way to iterate properties of an object. See [**Handlebars/Mustache - Is there a built in way to loop through the properties of an object?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058774/handlebars-mustache-is-there-a-built-in-way-to-loop-through-the-properties-of). You can instead format your data in such a way that Handlebars supports such as a plain array. I won't duplicate the code here, it is in the linked post.

Also, you shouldn't be placing `<script>` tags inside a fiddle's javascript plain. Use the `External Resources` section instead.