# Handlebars each not working

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, handlebars.js

So I have an array returning from the function call @mappingFunctions.getFunctionNames(), and I'm passing it into a handlebars template, but nothing's happening.

```
    @$el.append(@template({
      column: columns
      functionNames: JSON.stringify(@mappingFunctions.getFunctionNames())
    }))
```

In another file -

```
  getFunctionNames: ->
    names = []
    functions = @get('functions')
    for name of functions
      names.push(name)
    return names
```

It seems like the each is not being run -

```
<select class="map-columns">
  {{#each column}}
    <option value="{{ this }}">{{ this }}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>

<select class="map-functions">
  {{#each functionNames}}
    <option value="{{ this }}">{{ this }}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

Why?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` makes a string, while `#each` expects an object. See the problem? You don't show what `columns` is, but I suspect it has the same or a similar issue.

Comment: @Jon handlebars each expects an array, not object

Comment: so, I've passed in an array - and it still isn't working...or do you mean it has to be an object?

Comment: nvm - it works - post it up as an answer

Comment: @tsiki: [Wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058774/handlebars-mustache-is-there-a-built-in-way-to-loop-through-the-properties-of/17516837#17516837).

Comment: @Jon my apologies, haven't has the chance to use 1.0 extensively.

Comment: @tsiki: No problem. "expects an object" was not spot on either, an array is of course better -- the `JSON.stringify` threw me off there (started thinking about objects).

Comment: @praks5432: Added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string value to the template because that's what `JSON.stringify` produces. For `functionNames` the fix would be to remove the `JSON.stringify` and pass the straight array instead.

I 'm not sure what the deal with `columns` is, but it could very well be something similar.