# How can I get the names of name-value pairs in Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have this data structure:

```
flavors": {
            "sour": 0.16666666666666666,
            "salty": 0.16666666666666666,
            "sweet": 0,
            "meaty": 0.16666666666666666,
            "bitter": 0.16666666666666666
        }
```

My html is this:

```
<p>Flavors:</p>
   <ul>
     {{#Flavors}}
           <li>{{Flavours.Name}}</li>  // doesn't work  //
        {{/Flavors}}
     </ul>
```

What I'm trying to do is get at the name of the flavour: i.e. salty, sour, etc. I want to be able to cater for arbitrary values is the JSON, and not code them in the html block.

Answer (score 12):

You may iterate over the object in this way:

```
{{#each myObject}}
    Key: {{@key}} Value = {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

For details check this post: [Handlebars/Mustache - Is there a built in way to loop through the properties of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058774/handlebars-mustache-is-there-a-built-in-way-to-loop-through-the-properties-of)

Comment: I get an "uncaught exception error"

Uncaught Error: Parse error on line 17:
...lavors}}    Key: {{@key}} Value = {{thi
----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', got 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

the answer to my question is on this page:
[Handlebars/Mustache - Is there a built in way to loop through the properties of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058774/handlebars-mustache-is-there-a-built-in-way-to-loop-through-the-properties-of)

it's Ben's answer. Works very well indeed!

Answer (score -1):

Iterate over json and use key to get property names.

```
for (var key in obj) {
   alert(' name=' + key + ' value=' + obj[key]);
   // do some stuff here
}
```

Comment: I want to use handlebars if possible

Answer (score -1):

Your template should be like the following:

```
<p>Flavors:</p>
<ul>
 {{#each flavours}}
       <li>{{@key}}</li>
    {{/each}}
 </ul>
```

according with the documentation on the website.

Comment: The same error as above:
Uncaught Error: Parse error on line 17:
...lavors}}    Key: {{@key}} Value = {{thi
----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', got 'undefined'

Comment: Not really clear here why this is down voted. It is exactly the same syntax as the accepted answer plus some HTML tags.