# How do I access object keys in Handlebars templates?

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm passing this into my template.

```
modules: {
  left: [],
  center: ['card', 'progressChart', 'tableOfChildren'],
  right: ['activity', 'details', 'triggers']
}
```

I want to do something like this... (psuedo code that I don’t think will work)

```
{{#each region in modules}}
  <div class="{{region}}">
  {{#each region}}
    <div class="{{this}} module"></div>
  {{/each}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do

```
{{#each modules}}
  <div class="{{@key}}">
  {{#each this}}
    <div class="{{this}} module"></div>
  {{/each}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Reference: http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#iteration

Answer (score 8):

Probably [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058774/handlebars-mustache-is-there-a-built-in-way-to-loop-through-the-properties-of), where `Jon` provides the best solution:

For arrays:

```
{{#each myArray}}
    Index: {{@index}} Value = {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

For objects:

```
{{#each myObject}}
    Key: {{@key}} Value = {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

Note that only properties passing the `hasOwnProperty` test will be enumerated.