# Using @key inside of a loop works fine in development but not production

Tags: node.js, css, less

The code below works fine in development. I get the number (@key) appended to my class 'step' to produce...'step0, step1, step2, ...) but it does not work in production. Any suggestions on how to get this to work in production?

```
{{#careers}}
     <div class="col-sm-{{{../size}}} emp text-center"><span class="emp-role">{{this}}</span><span class="step{{@key}}"></span></div>
{{/careers}}
```

The overall goal was to produce numbered 'step' classes.

I then had some css to handle step0, step1, step2 and step3.

```
.step0 {
   ...
}
.step1 {
   ...
}
.step2 {
   ...
}
```

I tried to do this with an nth-child() but couldn't get it work work.

Comment: What is the result you get in production?

Comment: The result in production is "step" with no number appended to it. Would I need triple mustaches around my @key?

Comment: If everything else renders correctly, the problem is probably somewhere else. Without seeing your code, or knowing what template system you're using, though, it's pretty hard to say.

Comment: We're using app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', hbs.__express). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using {{@key}} when I should have been using {{@index}}.

[Answer found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058774/handlebars-mustache-is-there-a-built-in-way-to-loop-through-the-properties-of)