# mustache rendering for nested object hash

Tags: javascript, mustache

Here is my hash

```
{ 'name1': 
   { display_name: 'xxxx',
     description: 'desc',
     value: '2345' },
  'name2': 
   { display_name: 'yyyy',
     description: 'desc',
     value: null } }
```

My mustache template

```
{{display_name}} : {{value}}
```

This obviously doesn't work. How do I refer to the `display_name` and value of each element in the object?

Comment: Possibly related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058774/handlebars-mustache-is-there-a-built-in-way-to-loop-through-the-properties-of

Answer (score 1):

Either use the Mustache section, or specify what you're trying to view.

Mustache section:

```
{{#name1}}
  {{display_name}} : {{value}}
{{/name1}}
```

Sppecifying:

```
{{name1.display_name}} : {{name1.value}}
```

You can also loop through it if you want to, [as mentioned by @lemieuxter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058774/handlebars-mustache-is-there-a-built-in-way-to-loop-through-the-properties-of)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a Mustache [Section](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#sections) for the given key, e.g.

```
{{#name1}}
  {{display_name}}: {{value}}
{{/name1}}
```

More [examples](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#non-empty-lists) from the documentation. You can also [try mustache online](http://trymustache.com/) for a quick illustration.